# pinvoke to function which returns string array

Tags: c#, .net, c, pinvoke

I am trying to pinvoke to a function with the following signature:

```
const char ** SWDLLEXPORT org_crosswire_sword_SWModule_parseKeyList(SWHANDLE hSWModule, const char *keyText);
```

This returns an array of string.

I have example usage of this from c

```
const char **results = org_crosswire_sword_SWModule_parseKeyList(module, argv[2]);
while (results && *results) {
    printf("%s\n", *results);
    ++results;
}
```

The pinvoke I have tried is as follows:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME)]
public static extern IntPtr org_crosswire_sword_SWModule_parseKeyList(IntPtr hSWModule, string keyText);
```

And code to use it:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseKeyList(string keyText)
{
    IntPtr keyListPtrs = NativeMethods.org_crosswire_sword_SWModule_parseKeyList(_handle, keyText);
    return NativeMethods.MarshalStringArray(keyListPtrs);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> MarshalStringArray(IntPtr arrayPtr)
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arrayPtr);
    while(arrayPtr != IntPtr.Zero && ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arrayPtr);
        string key = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        yield return key;
        arrayPtr = new IntPtr(arrayPtr.ToInt64() + 1);
    }
}
```

This works for the first item and segfaults for the second on the PtrToStringAnsi line. What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to pinvoke to this function.

Comment: You're increasing the `arrayPtr` by 1 which shifts it 1 byte. But you want to make it point to the next array element, so you should add `IntPtr.Size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ code increments the pointer like this:

```
++results;
```

That increments the address by `sizeof(*results)` because that is how C++ pointer arithmetic works. So, suppose that `sizeof(*results)` is equal to 4, as would be the case on a 32 bit machine. Then `++results` will increment the address by 4.

Now, your C# code is different. The pointer is untyped and the compiler knows nothing about the underlying array element type. So your code

```
arrayPtr = new IntPtr(arrayPtr.ToInt64() + 1);
```

increments the address by 1. Instead you need to supply the missing type information. Like this:

```
arrayPtr = new IntPtr(arrayPtr.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size);
```

On top of that, your loop is implemented incorrectly. You fail to update `ptr` at the correct time. It should be:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> MarshalStringArray(IntPtr arrayPtr)
{
    if (arrayPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arrayPtr);
        while (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            string key = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
            yield return key;
            arrayPtr = new IntPtr(arrayPtr.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size);
            ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arrayPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

You might prefer to re-cast the method so that the code that it contains only a single call to `Marshal.ReadIntPtr`.

One final point. The C++ function looks like it might be using the `cdecl` calling convention. You should check what the definition of `SWDLLEXPORT` is. Your p/invoke is only correct if `SWDLLEXPORT` specifies `__stdcall`.

Comment: Don't I need to check the arrayPtr for IntPtr.Zero after I increment it each time?

Comment: @tramp No. Just a single check up front suffices.

Comment: I wish I could upvote multiple times. Once for IntPtr.Size, Once for loop incorrect, Once for calling convention. You where correct about all three.

Comment: @trampster well thanks. Feel free to upvote a couple of my other answers if you are desperate to give thanks! ;-)